# Problem withback sliding back on recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I use scroll down the recycler view my data are showing as I plan but when recyleview goes to end and I am sliding back to top, the sum for the day are broken. I can't figure how my data could being as good as being slide down for the first time.

Here is the code for the Adapter of the RecylerView:

```
   public class TimeOverallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimeOverallAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<TimeModel> list;
    int positionOfTheNextDay =0;
    // I commented this 16:58 - 10.07.2023
    int previousPosition = 0;

    boolean flag = false;

    public TimeOverallAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TimeModel> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TimeOverallAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View inflate = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_user_time,parent,false);


        return new MyViewHolder(inflate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TimeOverallAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Hiding the LinearLayout for last record of the day
        holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Hiding the LinearLayout for last record of the month
        holder.linearLayoutSummingRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Getting date from getTimeAdded
        Date date = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();

        //Setting date
        holder.date.setText(formattedDate(date));

        //Setting lasting time of the current record in String
        holder.hourInDay.setText(list.get(position).getTimeOverall());
        holder.beginTime.setText(list.get(position).getTimeBegin());
        holder.endTime.setText(list.get(position).getTimeEnd());


        // Comparing days
        if(list.size()>=2&& position<list.size()-1) {

            // Comparing work with this format
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            Date first = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
            Date second = list.get((position+1)).getTimeAdded().toDate();

            if((simpleDateFormat.format(first).equals(simpleDateFormat.format(second))))
            {
               Log.i("THE SAME DAY",position+"");
            }

            // 1 Comparing days, if the next day is different than current day, make summing
            if(!(simpleDateFormat.format(first).equals(simpleDateFormat.format(second))))
            {

                Log.i("THE Other DAY",position+"");

                // Assigning the position of the next day.
                positionOfTheNextDay = position + 1;


                //Showhing the LinearLayout for last record of the day
                holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                Date date1 = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
                holder.dateLastRecord.setText(formattedDateWithNameDay(date1));

                holder.dateLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.hours_last_record.setText("H");
                holder.hours_last_record.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                /*if(flag)
                {
                    previousPosition = position;
                    Log.i("TAG",previousPosition+"");
                }*/


                // summing time in the last day
                long sum = 0;
                for(int i = previousPosition;i<=position;i++)
                {
                    sum += list.get(i).getTimeOverallInLong();
                }

                previousPosition+= positionOfTheNextDay-previousPosition;

                String formattedTimeToLastRecord = formattedTime(sum);
                //sum=0;


                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setText(formattedTimeToLastRecord);
                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        }

        //Month overall
        if(position==(getItemCount()-1))
        {

            // Summing for all the record in ArrayList
            long sum = 0;
            for(TimeModel timeModel : list)
            {
                sum += timeModel.getTimeOverallInLong();
            }

            flag = true;

            holder.linearLayoutSummingRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.linearLayoutSummingRecord.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


            // Formatting date to "LIPIEC 2023" and seting to last record
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            Date date1 = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();


            holder.dateSumming.setText(dateFormat.format(date1));
            holder.dateSumming.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.hoursSumming.setText("H");
            holder.hoursSumming.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


            String formattedTimeToLastRecord = formattedTime(sum);


            holder.hoursInMonthSumming.setText(formattedTimeToLastRecord);
            holder.hoursInMonthSumming.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            // Summing first record of the day for one day only

            holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            Date date2 = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
            holder.dateLastRecord.setText(formattedDateWithNameDay(date1));

            holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setText(list.get(position).getTimeOverall());

            holder.dateLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.hours_last_record.setText("H");
            holder.hours_last_record.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



            // Checking if list size is more than 1 cous I need make a comparssion.
            // Checking in if(position==(getItemCount()-1)) cous I need to make comparssion in the last record
            if(list.size()>1) {

                //summing for the day
                // Work with this format
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

                Date first = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
                Date second = list.get((position - 1)).getTimeAdded().toDate();


                if ((simpleDateFormat.format(first).equals(simpleDateFormat.format(second)))) {


                    holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Date date3 = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
                    holder.dateLastRecord.setText(formattedDateWithNameDay(date3));

                    holder.dateLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.hours_last_record.setText("H");
                    holder.hours_last_record.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                }

                // summing for the current day
                long sum2 = 0;
                for (int i = positionOfTheNextDay; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    sum2 += list.get(i).getTimeOverallInLong();

                }

                String formattedTimeToLastRecord2 = formattedTime(sum2);


                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setText(formattedTimeToLastRecord2);
                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                //previousPosition =4;

            }
            else {
                holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                holder.linearLayoutLastRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Date date4 = list.get(position).getTimeAdded().toDate();
                holder.dateLastRecord.setText(formattedDateWithNameDay(date1));

                holder.dateLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.hours_last_record.setText("H");
                holder.hours_last_record.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                long sum3 = 0;
                for (int i = positionOfTheNextDay; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    sum3 += list.get(i).getTimeOverallInLong();

                }

                //previousPosition =4;

                String formattedTimeToLastRecord2 = formattedTime(sum3);


                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setText(formattedTimeToLastRecord2);
                holder.hoursInDayLastRecord.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }

        }
    }



    private String formattedTime(long sum) {
        long seconds = sum / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;

        seconds %= 60;
        minutes %= 60;

        String formattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        return formattedTime;
    }

    private String formattedDate(Date date)
    {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy",Locale.getDefault());

        return format.format(date);
    }

    private String formattedDateWithNameDay(Date date)
    {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yy",Locale.getDefault());

        return format.format(date);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView date,beginTime, endTime,hourInDay,dateLastRecord,hoursInDayLastRecord,hours_last_record,dateSumming,hoursInMonthSumming,hoursSumming;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutLastRecord,linearLayoutSummingRecord;

    public  MyViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        beginTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.startTime);
        endTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endTime);
        hourInDay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursInDay);
        dateLastRecord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_last_record);
        hoursInDayLastRecord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursInDay_last_record);
        linearLayoutLastRecord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        hours_last_record = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_last_record);

        linearLayoutSummingRecord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.summinglinearLayout);
        dateSumming = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_summing);
        hoursInMonthSumming = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursInDay_summing);
        hoursSumming = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_summing);

    }
}

}
```

and xml for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22.05.2023 r"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8 00"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16 00"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hoursInDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" H" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_last_record"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hoursInDay_last_record"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours_last_record"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/summinglinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_summing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hoursInDay_summing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours_summing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

I try many things, as seting previousPosition to some values but seems to be random due to resolution of the screen.